# Deleting a "first-time" cookie on form submit error

Tags: php, forms, cookies

I have a pop-up (CSS) layer on my homepage with a contact form in it that only pops up on the user's first visit. There is a cookie that expires after a year that tells the pop-up to appear. When the form is submitted, the cookie is created.

The form sends an email with a php script (this is my first foray into php). If I get an error, I want the cookie to be deleted, so that when the visitor goes back to the homepage, the popup still comes up. Here's what I have now:

```
if(empty($_POST['address']))
{
    setcookie("firsttimer", "", time()-3600);
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
```

The cookie isn't being deleted when I go back to the homepage. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use **setcookie** after you've outputted content into the browser. Not even one character of whitespace. Basically, before any HTML or any whitespace.